# How to resolve NonSPDMatrixException in h2o GLM classifier on large dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, h2o, glm

I am trying to run different classifiers using H2O estimator. While running the GLM classifier, however, I get an error message. Pasting the relevant code below.

```
CLASSIFIERS = {
'RandomForest': H2ORandomForestEstimator(ntrees=200, keep_cross_validation_predictions=True, stopping_rounds=2, score_each_iteration=True, model_id="rf_cv_all_folds_"+CLASSIFIER_DATE_STR, seed=1000000),
'RandomForest_depth6': H2ORandomForestEstimator(ntrees=200, max_depth=6,keep_cross_validation_predictions=True, stopping_rounds=2, score_each_iteration=True, model_id="rf_cv_all_folds_"+CLASSIFIER_DATE_STR, seed=1000000),
'GLM': H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(family= "binomial", lambda_ = 0, compute_p_values = True, remove_collinear_columns=True, keep_cross_validation_predictions=True, model_id="glm_cv_all_folds_"+CLASSIFIER_DATE_STR, seed=1000000), # todo: regularization? http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glm.html#regularization-parameters-in-glm
'GLM': H2OGeneralizedLinearEstimator(family= "binomial", lambda_ = 0, compute_p_values = True, remove_collinear_columns=True, keep_cross_validation_predictions=True, model_id="glm_cv_all_folds_"+CLASSIFIER_DATE_STR, seed=1000000, max_iterations=10000000), # todo: regularization? http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/glm.html#regularization-parameters-in-glm
'GBM': H2OGradientBoostingEstimator(ntrees=200, learn_rate=0.2, max_depth=20, stopping_tolerance=0.01, stopping_rounds=2, score_each_iteration=True, keep_cross_validation_predictions=True, model_id="gbm_cv_all_folds_"+CLASSIFIER_DATE_STR, seed=1000000),
'NaiveBayes': H2ONaiveBayesEstimator(keep_cross_validation_predictions=True,model_id="naive_bayes_cv_all_folds_"+CLASSIFIER_DATE_STR, seed=1000000)
}
```

When running the code on a **sample dataset**, I started getting the following 'UserWarning' for GLM classifier.

```
C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\h2o\job.py:69: UserWarning: Reached maximum number of iterations 50!
  warnings.warn(w)
```

However, when I tried running the code on the entire dataset (3gb), I get the following error message for GLM classifier.

```
   Job with key $03017f00000132d4ffffffff$_94bc493aa6606867c224fe00dac44410 failed with an exception: hex.gram.Gram$NonSPDMatrixException
    stacktrace: 
    hex.gram.Gram$NonSPDMatrixException
            at hex.gram.Gram$Cholesky.solve(Gram.java:664)
            at hex.gram.Gram$Cholesky$1.compute(Gram.java:607)
            at jsr166y.RecursiveAction.exec(RecursiveAction.java:160)
            at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
            at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doInvoke(ForkJoinTask.java:360)
            at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.invokeAll(ForkJoinTask.java:741)
            at hex.gram.Gram$Cholesky.solve(Gram.java:611)
            at hex.gram.Gram$Cholesky.getInv(Gram.java:617)
            at hex.glm.GLM$GLMDriver.fitModel(GLM.java:1119)
            at hex.glm.GLM$GLMDriver.computeSubmodel(GLM.java:1169)
            at hex.glm.GLM$GLMDriver.computeImpl(GLM.java:1254)
            at hex.ModelBuilder$Driver.compute2(ModelBuilder.java:218)
            at hex.glm.GLM$GLMDriver.compute2(GLM.java:571)
            at water.H2O$H2OCountedCompleter.compute(H2O.java:1395)
            at jsr166y.CountedCompleter.exec(CountedCompleter.java:468)
            at jsr166y.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:263)
            at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:974)
            at jsr166y.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1477)
            at jsr166y.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
```

Even when I increase `max_iternations = 1000000` for full dataset, I get the same error.

Any help in this regard would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the full code snippet that produces the error and include a description of your dataset (how many rows, columns, datatypes, and anything else you think might be relevant). Thanks!

Comment: This error is caused by Cholesky decomposition failure. It's possible to avoid the error by using regularization. 

However, it's not clear if that's what's happening in this case. If the error persists, we would like to see the data that causes it. Thanks.